# Qtimer doesn`t work. I think it is not updated

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I want send udp packet every 10ms.
I created QTimer, but SLOT doesn`t work. 
I created infinite loop with the output is timer->remainingTime() and it looks like the timer doesn't want to reset.
In output:
10
10
10
...
9
9
9
...
...
...
1
1
1
...
0
0
0
0
0
0
and then some zeros. Maybe this method is absolutely wrong. How can I still do it?

It`s my code:

usingbks.h

```
#ifndef USINGBKS_H
#define USINGBKS_H
#include "bks.h"
#include "sendtimer.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <thread>


class UsingBKS : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT


private slots:
    void sendPackets();

private:
    QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
    QUdpSocket* socket = new QUdpSocket(this);

...

    int TrandmissionStart(QString ip, quint16 port);
    int SendBKSOutBKSCond();
    int SendBKSOutPrimaKVCond2();
};

#endif // USINGBKS_H
```

usingbks.cpp

```
UsingBKS::UsingBKS()
{

}

UsingBKS::~UsingBKS()
{
    delete socket;
    delete timer;
}

void UsingBKS::sendPackets() {
    SendBKSOutBKSCond();
    SendBKSOutPrimaKVCond2();
}


...

int UsingBKS::TrandmissionStart(QString ip, quint16 port)
{
    socket->connectToHost(QHostAddress(ip), port);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(sendPackets()));
    timer->start(1000);
    while(1) { //it`s only for test
        std::cout << timer->remainingTime() << " " << timer->isActive() << std::endl; 
    }
    return 1;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "usingbks.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


    unsigned int Hz100 = 0, kHz1, kHz10, kHz100, MHz1, MHz10 ;
        Hz100 = 1;
        kHz1 = 1;
        kHz10 = 1;
        kHz100 = 1;
        MHz1 = 1;
        MHz10 = 1;
    UsingBKS* bks = new UsingBKS ();
    bks->SetBKSOutBKSCond(4, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0);
    bks->SetBKSOutPrimaKVCond2(4, 12,
                               static_cast<uint8_t>(Hz100),
                               static_cast<uint8_t>(kHz1),
                               static_cast<uint8_t>(kHz10),
                               static_cast<uint8_t>(kHz100),
                               static_cast<uint8_t>(MHz1),
                               static_cast<uint8_t>(MHz10), 0);

    cout << bks->TrandmissionStart("1.1.1.1", 10310);
    cout << "Trandmission started." << endl;
    delete bks;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: The line `while (1) {// it's only for test` is the one that can cause the error since an infinite loop blocks the event loop of Qt.

Comment: You also delete your `UsingBKS` object before you execute the application. That won't work well.

Comment: You don't need to have that destructor there. Those QObjects have a parent, and will be deleted by the parent. You don't even need to create them with `new`, because their lifetime ends before QObject destructor gets called, so they could be just plain member variables, saving a tiny bit of memory and processing overhead of using `new`.